# what this code does?

Tags: ubuntu

I don't know what this code does.

```
for i in $ ( ls )
do
   [  -r $i  ] && more $i
done
```

Comment: It does nothing due to a syntax error. What it's trying to do can be simplified to just `more *`

Comment: Jonny, please **[read the tour page](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)**, and [how to ask](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is not a forum but a site where we try to build a set of quality Q&As about *Unix & Linux*. Asking whether a particular user [anyone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/104307/anyone) can help you, is not a question about U&L. It **is** a question about the availability and capabilities of that user and is inappropriate here.

Comment: It's snide, unconstructive comments like this, where you deliberately misinterpret and twist the OP's words, that make new users (and some not-so-new users) believe that [SE] is hostile.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It goes through all the files in your current directory and if read permission is granted will send that file to be displayed by more command. Lousy code for couple of reasons though: it tries to parse output of ls, doesn't quote variables, and assumes theres no binary files. If you read binary file, it will display junk on screen

Comment: And it doesn't work at all because there's an extra space in it.

Comment: My version of `more` displays "******** /bin/ls: Not a text file ********" instead of junk.

Comment: Exactly right.  :)  And probably could be simplified into one line of find command